# Starting a dialog from conversationUpdate event in Node.js BotBuilder

Tags: node.js, botframework

I want to show the message and call a dialog when chatbot initialize. The below code shows the message. But, can not call a dialog.

```
bot.on('conversationUpdate', function (activity) {
// when user joins conversation, send welcome message
if (activity.membersAdded) {
    activity.membersAdded.forEach(function (identity) {
        if (identity.id === activity.address.bot.id) {
            var reply = new builder.Message()
                .address(activity.address)
                .text("Hi, Welcome ");
            bot.send(reply);
            // bot.beginDialog("initialize", '/');
            // session.beginDialog("initialize");
        }
    });
}});bot.dialog('/', intents);
```

Below is the code for **dialog**. I need to call below dialog when chatbot begins

```
bot.dialog('initialize', [
function (session, args, next) {
  builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Do you have account?", "Yes|No", { listStyle: builder.ListStyle.button });
}, function (session, args, next) {
    if (args.response.entity.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
        //session.beginDialog("lousyspeed");
        session.send("No pressed");
    } else if (args.response.entity.toLowerCase() === 'no') {
        session.send("Yes pressed");
        session.endConversation();
    }
}]).endConversationAction("stop",
"",
{
    matches: /^cancel$|^goodbye$|^exit|^stop|^close/i
    // confirmPrompt: "This will cancel your order. Are you sure?"
});
```

I tried below methods. But it is not working

```
        1. bot.beginDialog("initialize", '/');
        2. session.beginDialog("initialize");
```

Comment: How did you define "activity" here? When I use your code, it says that activity is not defined...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using single line code

```
bot.beginDialog(activity.address, 'initialize');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting this error because, although they have the same method *name*, the method signatures differ between `session.beginDialog()` and `<UniversalBot>bot.beginDialog()`.

This can be a bit confusing since the first argument to `session.beginDialog()` is the `dialogId`, but when using `bot.beginDialog()` the first argument is the `address`, and the second param is the `dialogId`.

To solve this, call `bot.beginDialog()` with the correct input parameters as described in the SDK reference documentation - Eg. `bot.beginDialog(activity.address, dialogId);`

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.universalbot.html#begindialog

You can also see the full method signature in the [botbuilder.d TypeScript definition file](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/7b70cfd/Node/core/lib/botbuilder.d.ts#L3931) here:

```
/** 
 * Proactively starts a new dialog with the user. Any current conversation between the bot and user will be replaced with a new dialog stack.
 * @param address Address of the user to start a new conversation with. This should be saved during a previous conversation with the user. Any existing conversation or dialog will be immediately terminated.
 * @param dialogId ID of the dialog to begin.
 * @param dialogArgs (Optional) arguments to pass to dialog.
 * @param done (Optional) function to invoke once the operation is completed. 
 */
beginDialog(address: IAddress, dialogId: string, dialogArgs?: any, done?: (err: Error) => void): void;
```